Form.io trigger all error messages of each field after clicking terms and conditions
Im currently validating my form, now theres this another requirement that they want the error messages that I set to each field to display if they are empty once I click the terms and conditions.
I tried adding it on validations tab but it doesnt actually get triggered if I click the terms and conditions. Is this actually possible on Form.io? thanks!
tried adding some conditions on validations tab.
tried adding some conditions on the logic tab.

Of course it is possible, I guess you are not targeting it well or something.
Here's a step by step on how to go about it and some simple code snippets that could help.

Step 1: Add Custom Validation to Each Field
Open Your Form in Form.io:
Navigate to your form in the Form.io editor.
Select a Field to Validate:
Click on a field that you want to make required when the terms and conditions are checked (e.g., a text field).
Go to the Validation Tab:
Click on the field settings (gear icon).
Go to the "Validation" tab.
Add Custom Validation Logic:
Scroll down to find the "Custom Validation" box.
Add something of this JavaScript code to the "Custom Validation" box:

// Assume the field is valid initially
valid = true;

// Get the terms and conditions checkbox element
var termsCheckbox = 
document.querySelector('[name="data[termsAndConditions]"]');

// Check if the terms and conditions checkbox exists and is checked
if (termsCheckbox && termsCheckbox.checked) {
  // If the input field is empty, make it invalid
  if (!input) {
    valid = false;
    error = 'This field is required when terms and conditions are accepted';
  }
}


Step 2: Add Custom Logic to Trigger Validation on Checkbox Click
Select the Terms and Conditions Checkbox:
Click on the terms and conditions checkbox component.
Go to the Logic Tab:
Click on the field settings (gear icon).
Go to the "Logic" tab.
Add Custom Logic:
Click on "Add Logic".
Set the "Trigger" to "Change".
Set the "Action Type" to "Custom Action".
Add something of this JavaScript code in the "Custom Action" box:

// Get all components (fields) in the form
var form = instance.root;
var fields = form.getComponents();

// Loop through each field
fields.forEach(function(field) {
  // Check if the field is not the terms and conditions checkbox
  // and has a validation rule
  if (field.component.key !== 'termsAndConditions' && field.component.validate) {
    // Set the required validation based on the checkbox state
    field.component.validate.required = 
document.querySelector('[name="data[termsAndConditions]"]').checked;
    field.redraw();
  }
});


Final Step
Save and Preview Your Form: After adding the custom validation and logic, save your form and preview it.
Test the Validation: Try checking the terms and conditions checkbox and leaving the required fields empty to see if the error messages are displayed correctly.

